# Does a for loop reset each time the set changes in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have this project in Theory of Computation course and have this function in DFA class where it basically determines whether a specific state is reachable from the start state or not (similar to checking connectivity in a simple graph). I have this for loop:

```
def is_reachable(self, dest_state):
        reachable_states = [self.start_state]
        for state in reachable_states:
            for char in self.alphabet:
                if self.transition_function[state][char] not in reachable_states:
                    reachable_states.append(self.transition_function[state][char])
        return dest_state in reachable_states
```

My question is: Does the first for loop (parent for loop) reset every time something is added to the set or does it just keep going? Because if it resets every time then the time complexity of this function would not be very efficient.

Comment: Do you mean when appending to the list? The answer is no

Comment: Have you tried running something similar and seeing what the results are?

Comment: You can safely *append* to the list, because the list iterator hasn't reached it yet. The problems start when you shift elements in the list before or *at* the current element,  because the iterator only references a *position*, and doesn't see or care if the values in the list change around it.

Comment: @Axe319 I didn't actually, no. What I had in mind was when running the first for loop, it receives the set not as a dynamic set, but as a static one.

Comment: I make it a personal rule not to modify the container I'm iterating over. Saves a lot of potential grief.

Comment: Side note: you don't have any `set`s in your code; you have a `list`. Otherwise things would be quite different

Comment: @MarkRansom That is good practice tbh.

Comment: @gimix My apologies, set referred to the set of states in the theoretical sense as I was dealing with a set of states in theory. I misused the word.